# Semantic UI search dropdown API does not call immediately

Tags: semantic-ui

I have spent the last few hours trying to work out how to use the Semantic UI dropdown module. I'm almost there... My code works perfectly and retrieves from a remote dataset. My only issue is that the dropdown does not perform the search when focusing on the element (tabbing to it, clicking it, etc). I need it to perform an empty search when focused. The only way to do an empty search is to press space bar then backspace to bring up the whole dataset.

JavaScript

```
$('.qb .product .field').dropdown('setting', {
    apiSettings: {
        url: '<domain>/api/v1/product/find/{query}'
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="ui dropdown floating fluid search selection field">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id">
    <div class="default text"></div>
</div>
```

Remote JSON Object - Not all of them as there are many

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "name":"Voluptatem",
         "created_at":"2015-09-23 16:31:29",
         "updated_at":"2015-09-23 16:31:29"
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "name":"Excepturi",
         "created_at":"2015-09-23 16:31:29",
         "updated_at":"2015-09-23 16:31:29"
      },
      {  
         "id":3,
         "name":"Something",
         "created_at":"2015-09-23 16:31:29",
         "updated_at":"2015-09-23 16:31:29"
      }
   ]
}
```

So just to clarify. When typing "v" into the search box then product with ID 1 is visible. When I press backspace to provide "" all results are returned. I need the latter to show on element focus. And nothing seems to be working at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have had the same issue as you. One workaround I had, was to use the Semantic UI search function and set minCharacters = 0. However, if you need some of the more specialized features of dropdown (e.g. multiselect) then you are out of luck for now.

```
$('.search').search({
    minCharacters: 0,

    apiSettings: {
        ...
        ...
    }
});
```

This will give you a *dropdown like* GUI, but will only let you select a single element.

Comment: Thanks for a solution! I do unfortunately need to use the allowAdditions function which the search module does not have.. I created a really hacky solution by providing a jQuery trigger to type a space then remove it. It looks invisible to the naked eye and performs an empty search. I'm hoping someone provides a Semantic UI API solution though.